# Combining parametric polymorphism and polymorphic variants (backtick types)

Tags: ocaml, parametric-polymorphism, polymorphic-variants, row-polymorphism

Suppose I have a type consisting of multiple polymorphic variants (covariantly) such as the following:

```
[> `Ok of int | `Error of string]
```

Let's further suppose that I want to factor this definition into some kind of type constructor and a concrete type `int`. My first attempt was the following:

```
type 'a error = [> `Ok of 'a | `Error of string]
```

However, using a definition like this produces a really strange type error mentioning a type variable `'b` that doesn't appear anywhere in the definition.

```
$ ocaml
        OCaml version 4.07.0

# type 'a error = [> `Ok of 'a | `Error of string ];;
Error: A type variable is unbound in this type declaration.
In type [> `Error of string | `Ok of 'a ] as 'b the variable 'b is unbound
```

This `'b` is an autogenerated name, adding an explicit `'b` shifts the variable to `'c`.

```
$ ocaml
        OCaml version 4.07.0

# type ('a, 'b) error = [> `Ok of 'a | `Error of 'b ];;
Error: A type variable is unbound in this type declaration.
In type [> `Error of 'b | `Ok of 'a ] as 'c the variable 'c is unbound
```

Using the invariant construction `` [ `Thing1 of type1 | `Thing2 of type 2 ] `` appears to work fine in this context.

```
$ ocaml
        OCaml version 4.07.0

# type 'a error = [ `Ok of 'a | `Error of string ] ;;
type 'a error = [ `Error of string | `Ok of 'a ]
#
```

However, explicitly marking the type parameter as covariant does not salvage the original example.

```
$ ocaml
        OCaml version 4.07.0

# type +'a error = [> `Ok of 'a | `Error of string];;
Error: A type variable is unbound in this type declaration.
In type [> `Error of string | `Ok of 'a ] as 'b the variable 'b is unbound
```

And, just for good measure, adding a contravariance annotation also does not work.

```
$ ocaml
        OCaml version 4.07.0

# type -'a error = [> `Ok of 'a | `Error of string];;
Error: A type variable is unbound in this type declaration.
In type [> `Error of string | `Ok of 'a ] as 'b the variable 'b is unbound
```

Attempting to guess the name that the compiler will use for the unbound type variable and adding it as a parameter on the left also does not work and produces a very bizarre error message.

```
$ ocaml
        OCaml version 4.07.0

# type ('a, 'b) string = [> `Ok of 'a | `Error of string] ;;
Error: The type constructor string expects 2 argument(s),
       but is here applied to 0 argument(s)
```

Is there a way of making a type constructor that can effectively "substitute different types" for int in `` [> `Ok of int | `Error of string] ``?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This isn't an issue of variance, or parametric polymorphism, but of row polymorphism. When you add `>` or `<` it also adds an implicit type variable, the row variable, that will hold the "full" type. You can see this type variable made explicit in the error:

```
[> `Error of string | `Ok of 'a ] as 'b
```

Note the `as 'b` part at the end.

In order to alias the type you have to make the type variable explicit, so you can reference it as a type parameter on the alias:

```
type ('a, 'r) error = [> `Ok of 'a | `Error of string ] as 'r
```

Note also, in case you have or when you will, run into objects, that this applies there as well. An object type with `..` has an implicit type variable that you need to make explicit in order to alias it:

```
type 'r obj = < foo: int; .. > as 'r
```

Comment: Why does the invariant case ``[ `Ok ... `Error ... ]`` not introduce a new row type parameter?

Comment: There would be nothing to parameterize in that case, since that's the "whole" type. ``[`A | `B]`` won't unify with anything structurally different from itself.